# Host for Channel URI for WNS

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, wns

While requesting channel URI from WNS, the channel uri received is of the form :

```
 https://hk2.notify.windows.com/?token=#
```

Sometimes instead of hk2 it is seen as db3 in host of the channel URI. On what basis do we get the host of the channel URI? i.e in which cases do we get db3 and hk2 or is it random?

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to know the host of the channel URI. However, **The developer should never modify the channel URI and should consider it as a black-box string.** Please check the [**Important notes** in Requesting a notification channel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-windows-push-notification-services--wns--overview#important_notes1).

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I am just curious to know is there a basis of this differentiation of host, or is it simply random. Also I could not find anything related to domain on any wns documentation.